Writing small dataframe takes long time on databricks
I am querying a small db2 table which has 9 Milion rows and 40 columns. It takes 50 second to run a count on this dataframe and few hours to write it to delta format. The source table is a full reload each month so I only partition it to write/append it to a different partition in each monthly load. What am I doing wrong here?
The output file is around 600MB
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")

SCRIPT = "select * from DB.TABLE"

DF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("driver", props["driver"]).option("user", props["username"]).option("password", props["password"]).option("query", SCRIPT).load()

DF = DF.withColumn("DE_INSERTED_DATE", current_date()).withColumn("execution_date", lit(last_day_of_month))
    
DF.write.format("delta") \
      .option("path", "s3://PATH-TO-MY-TABLE") \
      .mode("overwrite") \
      .partitionBy("execution_date") \
      .saveAsTable("DATABASE.TABLE")
       #insertInto("DATABASE.TABLE") 



Cluster details


Why are you using such a big driver and no executors? If you want to optimize it choose a smaller driver maybe 4GB MEM and add like 4 executors of same memory and then run your code. Since you are going to write dynamic partitions there will be many partitions created and since you have no executor to do it in parallel it will do it sequentially.

There is only one value in my partition column on each run and its value is coming based on a lit function so number of executors shouldn't change anything. Regarding the cluster size, I will try it with the size you suggested and check if it gets any better. Thank you!

In this case before writing try repartition the dataframe to create some equal partitions based on any evenly distributed column or you can even hardcode the partitions for testing.
